# How to get the execution mode in cucumber at run time? if the test execution is for single scenario or it is for entire feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Feature: Welcome Screen

Scenario: Launch google and check url of pricing
Given validating url
Then click on pricing
Then validate pricing url
I have a feature file , how to get at run time in my hooks that weather the user ran the entire feature file or ran single scenario?

i tried to get the name but when i ran the feature file it is coming out to be same as when i ran the first scenario, how to dintinguish and get the execution mode at run time?